# Is there formula for this squared geometric (?) progression?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there non-recursive formula for the following sequence:
$$a_1=\frac12,$$
$$a_n=\frac12a_{n-1}^2+\frac12$$

If there is, how do you suggest I can determine it?

Comment: What makes you think there is a non-recursive formula for that sequence?

Comment: $a_n-a_{n-1}=(1/2)(a_{n-1}-1)^2$ but I'm not sure that helps.

Comment: I've consulted with a mathematician who told me "ah let me think about it, it will not be too complicated" but then he did not have time to do it (in 5 minutes). And without the square it has a closed form. But I'll change my question.

Comment: Never believe a mathematician.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making the change of variables
$$a_n=1-2x_n$$
the recursion relation transforms into
$$x_{n+1}=x_n(1-x_n).$$
This is a particular case of [logistic map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html) (with $r=1$). If it were solvable, I think it would be mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Solution_in_some_cases) along with $r=2,4$.

Comment: That is very interesting! :O